# append exact lines from file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This thing:

```
with open(filepath+filename, encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        rows_list.append(line)
```

appends all lines to pandas dataframe.

The question is - what have I write to append exact lines from file - for example lines with line numbers from 50 to 100?

Comment: You mean lines having **line number** from 50 to 100?

Comment: thx, exactly, i've edited the text in question

Comment: See if I answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module.

```
from itertools import islice

with open("file_name.txt") as f:
    # This will make an iterator(`lines_from_50_to_100`) 
    # that returns selected elements(from index 49 to 100) from the iterable(`f`)
    lines_from_50_to_100 = list(islice(f, 49, 100))
    print(lines_from_50_to_100 )
```